# How to prevent to get __RequestVerificationToken automatically in ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using asp.net mvc 5 and creating a form to login via ajax (server side requires `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`).

I don't have any problem in the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    

    <!-- more tags -->
}
```

but I'm getting error message

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted.

when I try to call this method:

```
//u is url string, f is FormData()
var submit = function (u, f) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: u,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: $($('#loginForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]')[0]).val(), model: f },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            /* successfull login */
            Custombox.close();
            window.location.href = '/?type=promotion'
        } else {
            /* server returned exception message */
            $('div.validation-summary-valid').html(data.ex)
        }
    }).fail(function (error) {
        /* connect to server failure */
        $('div.validation-summary-valid').html(data.ex)
    })
};
```

Here is the Headers snapshot:

[image: __]

Why duplicate `__RequestVerificationToken` and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are sending it twice.
Once explicitly by reading the input field value and second inside the `f` variable, which i assumes is a serialized form.

**Solution** : Remove the part where you are sending it explicitly.

You can simply serialize your form and send. This will include the RequestVerificationToken.

```
$(function () {
    $("#yourSubmitBtnId").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var f = $("#loginForm");
        var formData =   JSON.stringify(f.serialize());

        var u = f.attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: u,
            type: 'POST',
            data:formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
        }).done(function (data) {
           //do something
        }).fail(function (error) {
           //do something else
        });    

    });   
});
```

Comment: I've checked again.I didn't append `__RequestVerificationToken` to the `f`. Also, you can see in the image, it's duplicate name, not duplicate value.

Comment: Try simply serializing and sending the form data. see my edit